# Padding in ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am doing a comparison with imagemagick on a project. I have a reference image and test image. I deleted few lines to make changes in test image. This reduced the size of test image. Is there any way that if I could add some white padding at bottom to test image so that while comparing reference image and test image the size of two images remains same.

Please help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```sh
convert -border 5x5 inputimage.png outputimage.png
```

This command will draw a 5x5 pixel border around your image. Further, you can selectively control at the edges, color and size of the borders drawn on an image. This [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#border) will show how to do that.

Comment: I'm curious how to make the border a percentage of the total image size? like 50%? Presuming the image size is dynamically generated... EDIT: I just did `50%x50%` and it just worked magically

Comment: Wasn't part of the question, but if, like me, you'd like the padding to be _transparent_ you can add the `-bordecolor "rgba(0,0,0,0)"` option.